# change rel attribute to data in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I try to make a HTML5 Validation. It is mentioned that i should not use rel attributes because i have to use registred keywords.
I searched some articles and changed all 'rel' to 'data-id' but then the script stops to work properly. I suggest to change the rel-attributes but i dont know to change this two code lines. I use the code for a style-changer on a webpage.

```
switchStylestyle(this.getAttribute("rel")); 
$('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i)
```

Jquery listened below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.styleswitch').click(function()
    {
        switchStylestyle(this.getAttribute("rel"));
        return false;
    });
    var c = readCookie('style');
    if (c) switchStylestyle(c);
});

function switchStylestyle(styleName)
{
    $('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i) 
    {
        this.disabled = true;
        if (this.getAttribute('title') == styleName) this.disabled = false;
    });
    createCookie('style', styleName, 365);
}
```

HTML5 listened below:

```
     <li><a href="#" rel="light" class="styleswitch">Light</a> </li>
     <li><a href="#" rel="dark" class="styleswitch">Dark</a> </li>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the rest of the code starting from `$('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i)`

Comment: if you change the attribute name in html, change the same in the script. Note that `<a>` disabled is no longer supported

Answer (score 0):

I guess is should something like this, but it does not work.

```
switchStylestyle(this.getAttribute("data-id")); <-- jquery
<li><a href="#" data-id="light" class="styleswitch">Light</a> </li> <--html5
```

Thanks for you hint. I guess i still need the 'a' think because i use a framework (bootstrap). (offtopic)

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.styleswitch').click(function()
        {
            switchStylestyle(this.getAttribute("rel"));
            return false;
        });
        var c = readCookie('style');
        if (c) switchStylestyle(c);
    });

    function switchStylestyle(styleName)
    {
        $('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i) 
        {
            this.disabled = true;
            if (this.getAttribute('title') == styleName) this.disabled = false;
        });
        createCookie('style', styleName, 365);
    }
})(jQuery);



function createCookie(name,value,days)
{
    if (days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name)
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name)
{
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```